# Using CDockingManager with CMDIFrameWnd

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I was able to make a simple docking window in a proof of concept project using CFrameWndEx but in my main project, we use CMDIFrameWnd which you apparently have to use CDockingManager.

I plan on taking the already existing windows in the large program I am working on dockable so i plan on making a class that extends CDockablePane and have the existing windows extend the custom class.

How do I use CDockingManager with the CMDIFrameWnd (any examples out there)? And am I going about this the right way?

Comment: There is alaso a CMDIFrameWndEx that extends all new Features of MFC.Next...

Comment: Nah not possible for me in this case but thanks that helps

Comment: I cant find any examples of CDockingManager via google either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that it is practically impossible to have a docking view unless you use a 3rd party library called BCG. Here is the link to the library [BCGSoft](http://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgcontrolbarpro.htm).

The project in particular to look at is called "DockingView". When you install the trial you can run and view the project. You will see that they had to rewrite a lot of the core MFC code in order to allow for docking views. It works great but it literally costs an arm and a leg to buy the license for it. So If you REALLY need to rework your MFC project its worth it.